# How can i get a child class of "this" object

Tags: typescript

So, i want to make some useful thing in typescript

```
interface Object {
    safeCall(func: (obj: === typeof this ===) => any | null);
}

Object.prototype.safeCall = func => {
    try {
        const value = func(this);
        return value ? value : null;
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
};

interface MeasureUnit {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

interface Product {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    measureUnit: MeasureUnit | null;
}

const product = fetch('....some request');

// obj.measureUnit can be null
const measureUnitID = product.safeCall(obj => obj.measureUnit.id)
```

So, the problem is, that i can't handle type inference, and i don't have all profit of type system, such as autocomplete, type validation, compilation check and other

How can i catch type of child class?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the function generic and use the generic type as the type of `this`, and forward the type to the callback. I also added a generic type parameter for the result, this might also be useful.

```
interface Object {
    safeCall<T, TResult>(this: T, func: (obj: T) => TResult | null) : TResult | null;
}
// We use a regular function not an arrow function because 
// the arrow function would capture this from declaration context
// while we want to use as this whatever object the function gets called on
Object.prototype.safeCall = function<T, TResult>(this: T, func: (obj: T) => TResult | null) : TResult{
    try {
        const value = func(this);
        return value ? value : null;
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
};
declare var product: Product;
const measureUnitID = product.safeCall(obj => obj.measureUnit.id) //obj will be Product
```

Comment: Worth noting: Notice how @Titian used the full `function() {}` form for the prototype, and not an arrow function. This ensure that `this` is correct.

Comment: Yes, i should have mentioned that as well, changed it out of reflex, will add an explanation, 10x